# PHP, phpmyadmin, html, javascript

Tags: javascript, php, json

I am having an issue ordering into a table primary id values which auto-increment from phpmyadmin and adding them into a table from recent to latest (greatest to lowest) can i get some help? I am using json to get php to javascript. This code only shows the table from latest to recent.

```
$app->get('/proyects/all', function () use($servername, $dbname, $dbuser, $dbpassword)
{

$response = array();

try
{
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpassword);

    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM proyectos");

    if ($stmt->execute())    {
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
    }


    $conn = null;

    if(!empty($result))
    {
        $response['proyects'] = array();
        foreach ($result as $key => $value)
        {
            $response['proyects'][$key] = $value;

        }
        $response['success'] = true;

        echo json_encode($response);
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        $response['success'] = false;
        $response['message'] = "Proyects not found";

        echo json_encode($response);
        return;
    }

}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    $response['success'] = false;
    $response['message'] = $e->getMessage();

    echo json_encode($response);
    return;
}
});

<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function()
     {
        $.ajax(
        {
            url: path+'/proyects/all',
            type: 'get',
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(json)
            {
                console.log(json);

                if (json.success)
                {
                    $.each(json.proyects, function( index, value ) {

                      $('#proyecs').append('<tr><td>'+value.idproyect+'</td><td>'+value.pdescription+'</td><td>'+value.presponsible+'</td><td>'+value.pdateini+'</td><td>'+value.pdatefin+'</td><td>'+value.pstatus+'&#37</td><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Details</button></td></tr>');
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    Materialize.toast(json.message, 5000, 'red accent-4');
                }
            },
            error : function(e, settings, exception)
            {
                Materialize.toast("Oops! an error has ocurred", 5000, 'red accent-4');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

@sesonrario @rex sorry forgot the code

Comment: How can we help you if you dont share your code to us?

Comment: You should share more context around the problem you're experiencing. It's very unlikely that someone can help you using just the info you left in the question. What (specific) issue are you running into? What isn't working? What have you tried? Also sharing relevant code could help greatly.

Comment: Added code @sensorario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could

```
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM proyectos order by id");
```

solve your problem?

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate it. oder by id DESC solved it